# How to display column names from multiple table using sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have created the following tables and have inserted these values:

```
create table customer (cid int, cname varchar(25), email varchar(25), phone int, status varchar(25), primary key (cid));
create table accounts( cid int, account int, atype varchar(25), balance int, foreign key(cid) references customer(cid));
create table address( cid int, street varchar(25), city varchar(25), country varchar(25), foreign key(cid) references customer(cid));




insert into customer values (101,'A', 'a@gmail.com', 99,'active');
insert into accounts values (101, 123, 'SA', 1000);
insert into address values (101, 'HMT','Blore','India');

insert into customer values (102,'B', 'b@gmail.com', 199,'active');
insert into accounts values (102, 123, 'CA', 2000);
insert into address values (102, 'Jayanagar','Blore','India');
```

My objective is to display cname, account and balance of the customers whose status is active.

I have tried writing the query using this: (I am unable to print the column cname using this) But it displays the rest.

```
select account, balance
from accounts
where cid in (select cid from customer where status = 'active');
```

this does not work:

```
select cname, account, balance
from  customer, accounts
where cid in (select cid from customer where status = 'active');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to join the two tables on the common customer ID.

```
SELECT c.cname,
       a.account,
       a.balance
       FROM customer c
            LEFT JOIN accounts a
                      ON a.cid = c.cid
       WHERE c.status = 'active';
```

Comment: Thank, It works fine. But I have a query on this, Why are you using Left Join? as it pulls out all the records from the left table. and can lead to errors when other data records are available right?


But I have found an alternative way to implement it.  I have posted it as an answer. Could you please have a look at it and let me know your reviews.

Comment: @User27854: Because with a left join you'll get all active customers, even if they don't have an account. You didn't state you want them filtered out in your question. If you don't want active customers without an account (I guess that's what you consider "errors when other data records are available"?) just change it to an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT customer.cname,accounts.account,accounts.balance FROM customer INNER JOIN accounts ON accounts.cid = customer.cid WHERE customer.status = 'active';
```

Comment: I have tried this and it works fine.  But I have found another way to implement it. I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way that worked for me:

```
    SELECT  cust.cname, 
            acc.account, 
            acc.balance 

            FROM  customer cust, 
                  accounts acc

            WHERE cust.cid=acc.cid 
            AND acc.cid IN 
             (select cid FROM customer WHERE  status='active');
```

Comment: You're doing an `INNER JOIN` when you cross join customers and accounts and then have a condition in the `WHERE` clause, that compares their customer IDs. You're just writing it in a manner not generally well received as the more verbose `INNER JOIN` syntax is considered clearer to read and understand by most people.

Comment: And your subquery is absolutely unnecessary. You already have access to the customer's record, so you can just go straight ahead an check if the status is active in the `WHERE` clause. At best the subquery gets optimized away and just makes the query harder to read and understand. Or it might even make the query's processing slower.